# How do I change the progress bar in Microsoft Player Framework?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

In Preview 2 of the Microsoft Player Framework they added an indeterminate buffering progress bar. How can I change that to the ring or remove it so I can continue using the ring I already have in place?

EDIT: I am currently using the released version from November 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the Xaml version of the player framework you can set BufferingPlugin.BufferingViewStyle to override the style of the BufferingView (which is where the progress bar is defined).

Comment: I need the same way, but I am new to xaml. Please can you provide me the xaml the above technical words go over my head.